# How to handle concurrency issue NodeJS with Redis

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

My requirement

- Read the token from Redis which is not reserved for application(it's application value is not set).
- Update this non-reserved token with given application name and Other threads should not get same token for reservation.

```js
static async reserveNewTokens(indextype: string, numberOfNewTokensForReservation: number, appname: string) {
    mgLogger.debug(this._module, "reserveTokens()", "start");
    
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfNewTokensForReservation; index++) {
        const nonReserverdToken = await LicenseDbManager.getNonReserverdToken(indextype);
        LicenseDbManager.reserveNewForProject(nonReserverdToken.documents[0].id, appname)
    }
    mgLogger.debug(this._module, "reserveNewTokens()", "end");
}
```

After execution of above code I observed that same token is override with two application names.   Code is executed on subscription of Redis pub/sub channel. Please let me know how can I solve this issue, I am using node-redis.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `EXISTS`/`GET` to check if the token does not exists and only then set it, you can use `SET` with the `NX` (stands for not exists) modifier:

```js
let reply;
do {
  reply = await client.set(generateTokenKey(), 'value', {
    NX: true
  });
} while (reply === null)
```